# In order to create an access mdb file to download do you have to have a phsyical location for the db?

Tags: asp.net, xml, ms-access, memory, memorystream

I would like to create an mdb access file and populate it all in memory and spit it back out to the UI for users to download locally, but I can't see anyway around first having to specify a physical location for the mdb when trying to create it. Is it possible? I am able to create recordsets in memory but I can't seem to create an mdb access file from that record. Maybe converting to XML first?

Comment: Please consider an [edit] to your question explaining why you would want to avoid simply creating a file in %TEMP% and then deleting it when you're done with it. Performance? Security? Some other reason?

Comment: That's the alternative. My question was an attempt to avoid that route.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to save it somewhere as a physical file.

If it only contains data, you can - of course - also export these to any non-native file format you will be able to let your users import.